# 3D plot with constraints

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Given the 3D plot `Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]`, how can one highlight the portion with $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) as follows:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &}, Mesh -> {{{1, Directive[Blue, Thick]}}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, style the mesh line using the option [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]]
```

> same picture

If you wish you can use different styles for the regions `x + y < 1` and `x + y > 1` using the option [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html):

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# + #2 &},
 Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick],
 MeshShading -> {Pink, Yellow}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotLegends -> Column[{SwatchLegend[{Pink}, { "x + y < 1"}], 
    LineLegend[{Directive[Blue, Thick]}, { "x + y == 1"}], 
    SwatchLegend[{Yellow}, { "x + y > 1"}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

`x + y == 1` is the border between the two regions

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y < 1]],
 Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 2 π}, {y, 0, 2 π},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5, ColorData[97][2]],
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x + y > 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: But the region is an *equality*... not an *inequality*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - the equality is the shared border of the two regions

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Plot3D[Sin[x y],
  {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
  PlotPoints -> 80,
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]];

b = Graphics3D[
  InfinitePlane[{ 1/2, 1/2,0}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1/2, -1/2, 0}}]];

Show[a,b]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[Plot3D[{ConditionalExpression[ Sin[x y], x + y > 1], 
   ConditionalExpression[ Sin[x y], x + y < 1]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 
   0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotPoints -> 50, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {LightCyan, Yellow}, Lighting -> "Neutral"], 
 ContourPlot3D[
   x + y == 1, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.0125]]] /. {x_Real, y_Real,
     z_Real} -> {x, y, Sin[x y]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]